# Redirect to same page in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I keep getting an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error each time i try to redirect to same page in django. I tried using return **HttpResponseRedirect('')** and **return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)** of which gave a blank screen and a **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error respectively. I have equally tried :

```
**views.py**
class Test(DetailView):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if check.objects.filter(active=True):
            return redirect(reverse('service', kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk}))
        else:
           render(self.request, 'page/details.html') # redirect to same page.
```

### **url.py**

```
path('test/<int:pk>/details', Test.as_view(), name='details'),
path('check/secure/<int:pk>', Others.as_view(), name='service'),
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201152/discussion-on-question-by-flow-redirect-to-same-page-in-django).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above was resolved finally with the following,

In your views, you can render the page instead of redirecting to it like so,

```
class Test(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if check.objects.filter(active=True):
            return redirect(reverse('service', kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk}))
        else:
           return render(self.request, 'page/details.html', {'jobs': Jobs.objects.all()}) # redirect to same page.
```

Then in your template, you can just render the list with a forloop,

```
{% for job in jobs %}
     {{ job }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!